# PNP4Nagios not displays graph

Tags: nagios

I have successfully installed PNP4Nagios 6.0 and added host/service details to get the graph but it is not displaying any graph.

When I try to check the configuration, I am getting the following error:

```
**[CRIT]  Command looks suspect (/bin/mv /usr/local/nagios/var/service-perfdata /usr/local/nagios/var/spool/xidpe/$TIMET$.perfdata.service)**
```

Following is my commands.cfg and nagios.cfg configuration details. Is there anything should I change:

Commands.cfg

```
define command {
       command_name                             process-host-perfdata-file-bulk
       command_line                             /bin/mv /usr/local/nagios/var/host-perfdata /usr/local/nagios/var/spool/xidpe/$TIMET$.perfdata.host
}

define command {
       command_name                             process-host-perfdata-file-pnp-bulk
       command_line                             /bin/mv /usr/local/nagios/var/host-perfdata /usr/local/nagios/var/spool/perfdata/host-perfdata.$TIMET$
}

define command {
       command_name                             process-host-perfdata-pnp-normal
       command_line                             /usr/bin/perl /usr/local/nagios/libexec/process_perfdata.pl -d HOSTPERFDATA
}

define command {
       command_name                             process-service-perfdata-file-bulk
       command_line                             /bin/mv /usr/local/nagios/var/service-perfdata /usr/local/nagios/var/spool/xidpe/$TIMET$.perfdata.service
}

 define command {
        command_name                             process-service-perfdata-file-pnp-bulk
        command_line                             /bin/mv /usr/local/nagios/var/service-perfdata /usr/local/nagios/var/spool/perfdata/service-perfdata.$TIMET$
}

define command {
       command_name                             process-service-perfdata-pnp-normal
       command_line                             /usr/bin/perl /usr/local/nagios/libexec/process_perfdata.pl
```

nagios.cfg

PNP settings - bulk mode with NCPD
    process_performance_data=1
service performance data
    service_perfdata_file=/usr/local/nagios/var/service-perfdata

```
          service_perfdata_file_template=DATATYPE::SERVICEPERFDATA\tTIMET::$TIMET$\tHOSTNAME::$HOSTNAME$\tSERVICEDESC::$SERVICEDESC$\tSERVICEPERFDATA::$SERVICEPERFDATA$\tSERVICECHECKCOMMAND::$SERVICECHECKCOMMAND$\tHOSTSTATE::$HOSTSTATE$\tHOSTSTATETYPE::$HOSTSTATETYPE$\tSERVICESTATE::$SERVICESTATE$\tSERVICESTATETYPE::$SERVICESTATETYPE$\tSERVICEOUTPUT::$SERVICEOUTPUT$

service_perfdata_file_mode=a
service_perfdata_file_processing_interval=15
service_perfdata_file_processing_command=process-service-perfdata-file-bulk
```

host performance data
    host_perfdata_file=/usr/local/nagios/var/host-perfdata
    host_perfdata_file_template=DATATYPE::HOSTPERFDATA\tTIMET::$TIMET$\tHOSTNAME::$HOSTNAME$\tHOSTPERFDATA::$HOSTPERFDATA$\tHOSTCHECKCOMMAND::$HOSTCHECKCOMMAND$\tHOSTSTATE::$HOSTSTATE$\tHOSTSTATETYPE::$HOSTSTATETYPE$\tHOSTOUTPUT::$HOSTOUTPUT$

```
host_perfdata_file_mode=a
host_perfdata_file_processing_interval=15
host_perfdata_file_processing_command=process-host-perfdata-file-bulk
```

Thanks & Regards,
Arun